# How do i make a println list of random numbers with no duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

is there a way I can make the drawerList() method look at the output from the drawerNumber() and add them to an array. I want to store the outputs into an array list in order to find the duplicates and print out both the stored values and possibly make an if else statement that finds duplicates of the random numbers and mark those outputs as "already drawn" This is my first semester of CS and i am in the learning stages so i feel like what i'm trying to do is out of my knowledge and I'm not sure what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 


import java.util.Random;

class RandomNumbers{
    public static void main(String [] args){

 System.out.println(drawerNumbers());
}

//drawerNumbers()-draws new numbers



public static int drawerNumbers(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(75)+1;
    return num;
}

//  drawerList()- List of numbers drawn
 public static int drawerList(){ //Method.
  String p = Integer.toString(drawerList()); //Convert method into string in order to be put in array
int[] numbers = new int[p.length()]; // creates the array to store the values

//
```

After this not sure how to make the outputs be listed to the console and how to make the program find the duplicate random numbers.

---

### `

1. Heading

` ##

Answer (score 1):

It seems your intention is to randomly pick numbers between 1 and 75 without repeating a number. This is most easily done by inverting the problem to randomly *ordering* the numbers 1-75 then iterating through them:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(75);
for (int i = 1; i < 75; i++)
    nums.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(nums);
```

Now they are in random order, just use them one by one:

```
for (Integer i : nums) {
    // use i
}
```